Completeness meaning (complete basis vs complete metric space)
Today my professor started talking about the formalism of QM.
We talked about the eigenvectors of a Hermitian operator (over Hilbert space) as a "complete set". He also mentioned briefly that $H$ space is a complete metric space, i.e., every Cauchy sequence of vectors in $H$ converges in $H$ (has a limit in $H$).
If we consider the eigenfunctions of a self-adjoint operator, we know they form a basis for the vector space of the self-adjoint operator (according to the spectral decomposition theorem). In quantum mechanics, we look at self-adjoint operators over Hilbert spaces. By definition, a Hilbert space is a complete metric space.
Is there a connection between the fact that the eigenfunction basis of self-adjoint operators (when the dimension is no longer finite) is complete and the fact that the space is a complete metric space? If the eigenfunction basis is complete, it means we can span every vector in the Hilbert space using the eigenfunctions, but how does this relate to the fact that every Cauchy sequence of vectors in the Hilbert space has a limit within the space?
Also, we call a subset of a vector space spanning if we can write every element of the vector space as a linear combination of the vectors in the subset. Why do we call this spanning property "completeness"?
Could you point me to resources that deal with these notions?
I read this and this, but I still don't get it.

@TobiasFünke your link sends to a dead end...  "Page not found" to be exact.

@ZeroTheHero: Try https://mathoverflow.net/q/349245/

You can have an incomplete inner product space with a complete orthonormal basis. For example, let $X$ consist of complex continuous functions on $[-\pi,\pi]$ with the inner product $\langle f,g\rangle = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(s)\overline{g(s)}ds$. This is an inner product space that is not complete with respect to the norm $\|f\|=\langle f,f\rangle^{1/2}$. However, $\{ e^{inx} \}_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}$ is a complete orthonormal basis of $X$.

No, there is no connection. I don’t even think mathematicians call a set of vectors such that the closure of their span is the whole topological vector space « complete », so that the vocabulary collision may only exist in physics references.
I don’t really think there is something worth add, but anyway: consider the space of complex-valued polynomials, endowed with any of the well-known scalar products one can put on it, and consider the orthonormal family of polynomials which respect to the scalar product (for example, the Hermite polynomials). The space is not complete (because it has an infinite countable basis), but the family is « complete » because it spans the whole vector space.
Let me also add that the set of the elements of an orthonormal family also can be seen as a metric space, with the induced metric. Since the vectors are orthonormal, there are all $\sqrt{2}$ apart from each other. Therefore, this metric space is discrete, and therefore is complete as a metric space, even if the family does not span a dense subspace (so, even if the family is not « complete » in the physics sense).

They are not exactly the same thing but they are related. Even to define an orthonormal basis of a Hilbert space we have to talk about limits. You say:

Because if the eigenfunction basis is complete, it means we can span every vector in the Hilbert space using the eigenfunctions

but your question makes it unclear whether you're familiar with the details of what "span" means here. It does not mean taking finite linear combinations (which is what it means in ordinary linear algebra); it means taking the limits of all finite linear combinations, or equivalently, taking the closure of the subspace of finite linear combinations. (Although I guess a physicist would just directly talk about infinite linear combinations.)
We're not guaranteed that this construction behaves the way we'd like it to unless we require that the underlying inner product space is a complete metric space, which is why that's part of the definition of a Hilbert space. Without getting into the details (which I haven't had to think about in awhile anyway), there are various parts of various arguments where you'd like to take limits, so you'd like to know that those limits exist.
The sense in which "completeness" is an appropriate term in both cases is that they both have to do with us "not missing any vectors," having all the vectors we "should have."
